# JWT token Expiration is not getting set to the required time

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using JWT in my .Net Core application and I'm using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt (5.6.0)
I'm trying to set the expiration time as follows:

```
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                "www.site.com",
                "www.site.com",
                claims,
                expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5),
                signingCredentials: credentials);
```

My computer's time is 2.38 pm and tokens validate to propertys' value is 9.43 pm.
Which has to be 2.43 pm.

My Startup.cs configurations are as bellow:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["Authentication:Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = Configuration["Authentication:Issuer"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Authentication:Secret"]))
            };
        });
```

What is the reason for this?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are living a location where the time zone is UTC -7. `DateTime.UtcNow` 
returns UTC time, use `DateTime.Now` instead.